# Library to get input from a PS4 or Xbox controller?

Tags: input, controller, playstation

I am looking to control an ROV by using either a PS4 controller or an Xbox 360 controller. I plan to do this by connecting the controller to a computer and then sending that to the ROV. A little background information on the project is, we have the controller up top, which sends it to the computer, and then we will send from the computer to an Arduino on the ROV via Ethernet.

I have learned that this is possible on the PS3 controller by using Processing because another team did it, but I am unfamiliar with that language and don't have a PS3 controller. However, I have a PS4 and Xbox 360 controller.

From what I have researched, SDL could be an option for this, but I am looking for advice from more experienced people than me.

Answer (score 0):

My question got deleted by pissed mods, because it was "unrelated", but I asked the same. Anyway, I implemented my PS4 controller support with SFML like this. Other simple possibility would be SDL. XBox will be the same I guess. Have fun

Here some sample code..

```
sf::Joystick::update();

// Is joystick #0 connected?
m_bGamepadConnected = sf::Joystick::isConnected(0);

if(!m_bGamepadConnected) {
    return;
}

// Does joystick #0 define a X axis?
m_bStickLX = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::X);
m_bStickLY = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::Y);
m_bStickRX = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::Z);
m_bStickRY = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::R);
m_bStickL2 = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::U);
m_bStickR2 = sf::Joystick::hasAxis(0, sf::Joystick::V);

m_tJoystick.start(5);
QObject::connect(&m_tJoystick, SIGNAL(timeout() ), this, SLOT(updateGamepad() ) );
```

And this may help you ..

```
sf::Joystick::update();

float fStickLX = 0;
float fStickLY = 0;
float fStickRX = 0;
float fStickRY = 0;
float fStickL2 = 0;
float fStickR2 = 0;

// What's the current position of the analog sticks
if(m_bStickLX) {
    fStickLX = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::X) / 100;
}
if(m_bStickLY) {
    fStickLY = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::Y) / 100;
}
if(m_bStickRX) {
    fStickRX = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::Z) / 100;
}
if(m_bStickRY) {
    fStickRY = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::R) / 100;
}
// R2 and L2
if(m_bStickL2) {
    fStickL2 = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::U) + 100;
    fStickL2 /= 200;
}
if(m_bStickR2) {
    fStickR2 = sf::Joystick::getAxisPosition(0, sf::Joystick::V) + 100;
    fStickR2 /= 200;
}

if(m_fStickLX != 0 || m_fStickLY != 0 || m_fStickRX != 0 || m_fStickRY != 0 || m_fStickL2 != fStickL2 || m_fStickR2 != fStickR2) {
    m_bGamepadInUse = true;
} else {
    m_bGamepadInUse = false;
}

m_fStickLX = fStickLX;
m_fStickLY = fStickLY;
m_fStickRX = fStickRX;
m_fStickRY = fStickRY;
m_fStickL2 = fStickL2;
m_fStickR2 = fStickR2;

m_bButLPressed = isButtonPressed(0, 0);
m_bButDPressed = isButtonPressed(0, 1);
m_bButRPressed = isButtonPressed(0, 2);
m_bButTPressed = isButtonPressed(0, 3);

//qDebug() << "m_bButDPressed pressed: " << m_bButDPressed;
static bool bArmToggle = false;
if(m_bButDPressed && !bArmToggle) {
    m_bDeviceArmed = m_bDeviceArmed ? false : true;
    bArmToggle = true;
    qDebug() << "Device armed?: " << m_bDeviceArmed;
}
if(bArmToggle && !m_bButDPressed) {
    bArmToggle = false;
}
```